# Execute MySQL From Command Line with Zend Server

Tags: mysql, zend-server

EDIT: FYI - These queries are going to a MySQL db on a DIFFERENT server.  I am NOT querying the MySQL DB on my Mac.  However, it is using the LOCAL mysql client installed by Zend server.

UPDATE : This definitely seems to be something with MySQL configuration with Zend Server.  I got fed up and installed the MySQL 5.5.25 DMG for the Mac.  If I use the new path to the mysql client on my Mac, the queries run properly.

I've got Zend Server Community Edition on my Mac.

I need to execute a MySQL query from the terminal command line (not the mysql command line). On ALL of my servers with a traditional LAMP stack (not Zend Server), I can execute queries like this :

```
$ mysql -u USER_NAME -p PASSWORD -hSERVER_NAME -PTHE_PORT -e "SELECT NOW();"
```

On ALL of my other servers, I get this response :

```
+---------------------+
| NOW() |
+---------------------+
| 2012-06-20 18:34:21 | 
+---------------------+
$
```

On my Mac with Zend server, I get:

```
ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'NOW();'
```

If I use any other command such as this one on a non-Zend server, I get a valid response:

```
mysql -u USER_NAME -p PASSWORD -hSERVER_NAME -PTHE_PORT -e"use stp_downloads; select * from downloads limit 2;"
+--------------+-------------+---------------------+-----------------+ | downloads_id | statuses_id | download_stamp | order_number |
+--------------+-------------+---------------------+-----------------+ | 10001 | 5 | 2011-04-04 22:17:29 | DOWN00000004753 |  | 10002 | 5 | 2011-04-04 22:29:06 | DOWN00000004754 | 
+--------------+-------------+---------------------+-----------------+
```

If I run that command on my Mac with Zend server, I get :

```
/usr/local/zend/mysql/bin/mysql.client Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.54, for apple-darwin9.8.0 (i386) using readline 5.1
Copyright (c) 2000, 2010, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
This software comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY. This is free software,
and you are welcome to modify and redistribute it under the GPL v2 license
Usage: /usr/local/zend/mysql/bin/mysql.client [OPTIONS] [database]
.......
```

Followed by all the usage info.

Why can't MySQL on Zend Server properly process SQL statements using -e or --execute??

What am I doing wrong??

Thanks,
Justin

Comment: It has nothing to do (per se) to the Zend Server, just to the out-of-the-box configuration MySql get.

Comment: On a Mac, Zend Server installs MySQL.  So, yes it IS MySQL that is the problem.  However, it seems to be due to whatever configuration Zend either created or Zend received from MySQL.

Comment: Does not really matter, We know the problem is in the my.conf file, right? So, dive into it, most of the values there are self-explanatory